# Outside jQuery web app crash with MooTools

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mootools

App build on `jQuery`, `require.js`, `html`, `css` - some websites that consume this app have MooTools.js too and this framework conflicts with my app, can't combine with jQuery.

When then app is started, all outside sources like scripts and css that it needs to work, go into the head tag of the host webpage and HTML to `<div id="widget"/>`.

*Injection code below:*

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<link href="@(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppPathFE"] + "outside-ip/widget.css")" />
<script src="@(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppPathFE"] + "outside-ip/widget.js")"></script>

<div id="widget"></div>

<script>      
    $(function () {
        WG.initialize({
            urlFE: '@(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppPathFE"])',
            urlBE: '@(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppPathBE"])',
            theme: 'base',
            lang: 'en-en',
            cache: false,
            logging: true,
            talk: {
                url: '@(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppTalk"])',
                logging: true,
            },
            air: {
                url: '@(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppAir"])',
                logging: true,
            },
        });
    });       
</script>
```

Comment: you are doing a number of naughty things. you are injecting your version of jquery into every host page, potentially overwriting later versions of jquery there as you don't appear to have `noConflict`. you also assume that `$` is owned by `jQuery`, whereas it can be MooTools or PrototypeJS. you need to use closures in your code and wrap the version of `jQuery` to your own, making a widget that can be universally used requires you to be **non-obtrusive** and considerate of others, not messing up existing sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

MooTools uses `$` as a alias for `document.id`, which is basically is `document.getElementById` but with MooTools powers.

So if you change you code to this under you should be safe:
(you have of course to change all `$` to `jQuery` inside your script file also):

```
    jQuery(function () {
        WG.initialize({
```

instead of

```
    $(function () {
        WG.initialize({
```

You can also in your script code just Wrap all code in `(function($){ code here })(jQuery);`. So if your script exports `WG` to global space you could have:

```
var WG;
(function($){ 
    // all script code here, removing the var declaration inside the wrap function
})(jQuery);
```

Or just to `window.WG` inside your script.